# Eclipse MAT Analyser: Understanding leak suspect report

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I use the tool **Eclipse MAT Analyser** and observe the LEAK support has one problem as mentioned below,

```
One instance of "hudson.model.Hudson" loaded by "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @ 0x3c0001f48" occupies 2,129,624,192 (95.23%) bytes.

The memory is accumulated in one instance of "hudson.model.Hudson" loaded by "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @ 0x3c0001f48".



Keywords
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @ 0x3c0001f48
hudson.model.Hudson
```

What does this mean? What will be the cause of this?

**More Information :**

1) This object has the shallow size = 312 and retained size = 2000000000
   I understand shallow size means the size of one object and retained size is 2GB, So does it mean that 6410256 number of objects are alive?

2) It is the jenkins and I am trying to analyse jenkins with number of jobs, So How can I identify that this object is **unncessarily referenced** in memory (OR) What are the ways to free this up?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: The class `hudson.model.Hudson` has used about 2Gb of memory. Since we know nothing about your code we can't tell you why.

Comment: @greg-449 I understand that code is not there, But Could you please tell me Does it mean that GC is not collected for this?  I need to know what this error means in MAT

Comment: GC cannot collect the instance of `hudson.model.Hudson` because it is referenced somewhere. The two questions are, is it unnecessarily referenced and does the one instance really need that much memory?

Comment: @howlger I provided more informations please check this

Answer (score 2):

What this means and what causes it cannot be answered without analyzing the code. Eclipse MAT Analyser can only show where a more precise manual code analysis seems worthwhile.

1. The **[retained size](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/concepts/shallowretainedheap.html)** of X is the total size of objects which would be removed by GC when X is garbage collected. This means it **also contains sizes of instances that are referenced** somehow via X only.
2. To find out **where and why instances are referenced**, you need to understand the code:

   - Starting from the **[Dominator Tree](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/concepts/dominatortree.html)** of `hudson.model.Hudson`, look at the code to see why and how the instances are used.
   - Set a breakpoint and start the application in **debug** mode to see the current values of fields of an instance. You can also use so-called [Tracepoints](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/menus/run/ref-menu-run.htm) in constructors to get an output on the console without pausing the application every time an instance is created.