# OOM (Java heap) error due to org.postgresql.core.Field

Tags: java, hibernate, out-of-memory, heap-dump, oom

I have a Java application using Hibernate to connect to a PostgreSQL backend. Been getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error very frequently. Upon analysing the heap dump on OOM and comparing it with a heap dump taken during a normal run I noticed a significant increase in org.postgresql.core.Field objects. What could be the potential reason for this? Could it be due to improper closure of DB connections by Hibernate?

[image]

Jdk: 18

DB: Postgresql (42.3.5)

Hikaricp: 4.0.3

Spring boot: v2.7.0

Comment: Are you using Eclipse MAT? Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257636/eclipse-mat-analyser-understanding-leak-suspect-report

Comment: @aled No, VisualVm. Thanks, will check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.postgresql.core.Field` is a class from the postgresql driver. If you have these instances hanging around it seems that you are not freeing up jdbc resources.

In plain jdbc this would likely happen if you weren't calling `ResultSet.close()`, `Statement.close()` and `Connection.close()` to free up resources.

With hibernate these are wrapped via the hibernate `Session` so you need to ensure that you are freeing up `Session` resources once you are done with them.

How are you managing your hibernate `Session`s? Are you returning / closing resources once you are done with them?

From the [hibernate session javadocs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html)

> A typical transaction should use the following idiom:

```java
 Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

Comment: Sessions are managed by Spring data jpa. Following are the properties that I'm using:


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction

Comment: How do you obtain a session instance? How are you closing/returning the session instance? If you were using spring's [OpenSessionInViewFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) it would manage the session for you via a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: No, I'm not explicitly opening/closing a session. I suppose we are using OpenSessionInViewFilter given spring.jpa.open-in-view property is by default set to true.

Comment: `OpenSessionInViewFilter` will only free up the thread local associated with the current request thread. Are you doing anything with custom threads / thread pools? Are you perhaps selecting thousands of rows which causes the OOM?